# How to create a Live USB key for a SUSE distro on Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

I use Ubuntu on a daily basis and want to try Suse on my second laptop.

Neither Startup Disk Creator (both versions on the Ubuntu Universe) nor unetbootin allow me to use anything different than another Ubuntu distro to create the live USB key.

I don't use windows anymore, so doing this on a pc is not an option.

Is there any other way / application?

Comment: you can use unetbootin to create other linux distro live usb. Download iso and select iso file at diskimage option.

Comment: This question is probably relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225173/help-with-creating-bootable-usb-from-iso

Comment: Thanks Sudheer
Your reply meant the long way, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .iso is a "hybrid mode" image (like most Ubuntu and Debian images these days, have no idea about SUSE), then you can just write it directly to the USB just as if it was a CD-ROM drive.  For instance, using *dd*.

```
dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc oflag=direct bs=1048576
```

If the .iso is not a hybrid mode image, then you can use [UNetBootin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin), available from Ubuntu's repositories, which is an easy way to burn an ISO (for a Linux distro) to a USB key.

UNetBootin does not restrict you to using it with Ubuntu only - it will allow you to use an .iso you have previously downloaded, and that .iso can be of any distro.

Answer (score 0):

Download live ISO for gnome or kde from [here](http://software.opensuse.org/131/en).

You can use MultiSystem(tutorial and download link [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/))just an alternative, but you can also use unetbootin for SUSE.